# Unrar all file in directory without prompting

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, unrar

I tried:

```
find . -name "*.rar" -exec unrar x -o {} \;
```

Output:

> Extracting from ./setup.part2.rar
>
> Extracting from ./setup.part1.rar
>
> RORY/nsfw.zip already exists. Overwrite it ? [Y]es, [N]o, [A]ll,
>   n[E]ver, [R]ename, [Q]uit A

I can't have this prompting me; both hands occupied unfortunately. thought the -o flag would do it, but nope.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to specify `-o+` to enable automatic overwriting:

```
find . -name "*.rar" -exec unrar x -o+ {} \;
```

From `unrar` usage:

```
o[+|-]        Set the overwrite mode
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not list *.rar files in other directories (only where the command is run) using `maxdepth`. Remove print or messages on the screen with `-inul`.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.rar" -exec unrar x -o+ -inul {} \;`